# What are the default tab settings in visual studio 2010 for all the different file types?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, default

I was hoping to find a site that lists all the default settings somewhere so I don't have to install a fresh copy of VS or reset my settings to find out. My team is having a discussion on which settings to use for what, and wanted to know what Microsoft's defaults were for each.

Answer (score 1):

Just export your current settings, reset to the defaults, export those to a separate file, reload your original settings, and now you've got the default settings in an XML file.

Comment: How to: Share Settings Between Computers or Visual Studio Versions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x6229t8.aspx